# Save canvas from windows store app as image file

Tags: c#, canvas, windows-store-apps, visual-studio-2013

I'm looking for way to save canvas from windows store app, I have found:

```
private void CreateSaveBitmap(Canvas canvas, string filename)
     {
       RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
        (int)canvas.Width, (int)canvas.Height,
        96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
      // needed otherwise the image output is black
       canvas.Measure(new Size((int)canvas.Width, (int)canvas.Height));
       canvas.Arrange(new Rect(new Size((int)canvas.Width, (int)canvas.Height)));

renderBitmap.Render(canvas);

//JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
       PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
       encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));

using (FileStream file = File.Create(filename))
       {
         encoder.Save(file);
       }
     }
```

But that method won't work in windows store app (there is no 5 argument constructor for `RenderTargetBitmap` no `PngBitmapEncoder`). So my question is how can I save canvas from windows store app as some kind of image file (jpg, png, etc.) is there any way to do this?

Comment: @Dick, If u put canvas width and height in Xaml code no need to write canvas.ActualWidth or Height. Showing this type of Exception means you didn't set width and height of canvas .That's why it asking about the actual height or width.
Just check it. Happy Coding,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime

private async Task CreateSaveBitmapAsync(Canvas canvas)
{
    if (canvas != null)
    {
        RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
        await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(canvas);

        var picker = new FileSavePicker();
        picker.FileTypeChoices.Add("JPEG Image", new string[] { ".jpg" });
        StorageFile file = await picker.PickSaveFileAsync();
        if (file != null)
        {
            var pixels = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();

            using (IRandomAccessStream stream = await file.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
            {
                var encoder = await
                    BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
                byte[] bytes = pixels.ToArray();
                encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                                     BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
                                     (uint)canvas.Width, (uint)canvas.Height,
                                     96, 96, bytes);

                await encoder.FlushAsync();
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Error 1 'Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer' does not contain a definition for 'ToArray' and no extension method 'ToArray' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.Storage.Streams.IBuffer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\... 198 51 PhotoEditor1

Comment: Please mark the answer as accepted if my solution worked for you. It will be helpful to others.

Comment: just to note people here the change made was adding System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime library at the top of the code!

Answer (score 3):

I came across this reply and although it looked exactly what I was looking for it didn't work. Adding an error handler revealed:

Value does not fall within the expected range.

Finally I found that:

```
(uint)canvas.Width, (uint)canvas.Height,
```

were both 0. After replacing it with:

```
(uint)canvas.ActualWidth, (uint)canvas.ActualHeight,
```

it worked. No idea why it worked for Carlos28 and not for me, but with this change it worked for me too and so I thank Xyriod for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, Xyroid, for your idea and structure.
To get a version of CreateSaveBitmapAsync() to work on 04/24/20, I had to replace your `using` block with the following.
The changes of your hard-coded "96"'s, and the replacement of "bytes" with its definition, are optional.

```
using (Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream stream = await fileToWhichToSave.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite))
{
    Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder encoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapEncoder.JpegEncoderId, stream);
    encoder.SetPixelData(
        Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
        Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapAlphaMode.Ignore,
        (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
        (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
        Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
        Windows.Graphics.Display.DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView().LogicalDpi,
        pixels.ToArray());
    await encoder.FlushAsync();
}
```