# Windows 8 Store App: Export Canvas to PDF

Tags: xaml, pdf, windows-store-apps

I am trying to implement some export features for my windows store app and already found out how to export the canvas as image ([Save canvas from windows store app as image file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313245/save-canvas-from-windows-store-app-as-image-file)).

It is nice, but an export to pdf would be much better. Is there an option to save a canvas to a pdf file. Third-Party commercial libraries are also welcome. I found a lot of rendering libraries to view pdf files but no exporter yet.

I know iTexsharp, but my canvas is very complex, I want to avoid spending the time to reimplement this rendering process for the pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

I use PDFkit (pdfkit.org), which lets you use drawing code that is very similar of that of canvas. You can just copy the canvas code over and then make a few simple changes here and there to make it work.

For example everything in PDFkit is a function, so in canvas you'd do ctx.lineWidth = 2 but in PDFkit that becomes ctx.lineWidth(2). Also ctx.beginPath() you have to just ditch in PDFkit, just works fine without. Changes like this you have to make, but structurally everything is the same.